# How to push object value from first array to second array by id?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an 2 array, first array:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "jumlah_sd",
        "title": "Jumlah SD",
        "value": "1222"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "jumlah_smp",
        "title": "Jumlah SMP",
        "value": "1322"
    }
]
```

and second array with no value:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "jumlah_sd",
        "title": "Jumlah SD"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "jumlah_smp",
        "title": "Jumlah SMP"
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "jumlah_sma",
        "title": "Jumlah SMA"
    }
]
```

My question is, how to push by their "id" object value in first array to second array in JavaScript? And if there is no value in other object, so the value become "value": "" in second array.

Comment: just an idea . convert first array to a object for easy lookup then map through the second array and add the value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do is to create an object with the `id` as the key and `value` as value for easy lookup.
After that `map` through the second array and add the id using the lookup object.

```js
const arr1 = [    {        "id": 1,        "name": "jumlah_sd",       "title": "Jumlah SD",        "value": "1222"    },    {        "id": 2,        "name": "jumlah_smp",        "title": "Jumlah SMP",        "value": "1322"    }]

let arr2 = [    {        "id": 1,        "name": "jumlah_sd",        "title": "Jumlah SD"    },    {        "id": 2,        "name": "jumlah_smp",        "title": "Jumlah SMP"    },{        "id": 3,        "name": "jumlah_sma",        "title": "Jumlah SMA"    }]

const idLookup = arr1.reduce((acc,{id,value}) => {
  acc[id]??=value
  return acc
},{})

arr2 = arr2.map((x) => ({...x, value: idLookup[x.id]||""}))

console.log(arr2)
```

Another approach is to use `find` inside `map` but it will intuitively be slower since the `find` is called in each iteration inside the `map`

```js
const arr1 = [    {        "id": 1,        "name": "jumlah_sd","title": "Jumlah SD",        "value": "1222"    },    {        "id": 2,"name": "jumlah_smp",        "title": "Jumlah SMP",        "value": "1322"    }]

let arr2 = [    {        "id": 1,        "name": "jumlah_sd",        "title": "Jumlah SD"    },    {        "id": 2,        "name": "jumlah_smp",        "title": "Jumlah SMP"    },    {        "id": 3,        "name": "jumlah_sma",        "title": "Jumlah SMA"    }]

arr2 = arr2.map((x) => {
  const entry = arr1.find(({id}) => x.id === id)
  return {...x,value:entry?.value||''}
})

console.log(arr2)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer,I learned a lot from it